# Getting VS Code's C++ intellisense to deal with WinAPI types

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-code

So, I'm using WinAPI in a C++ project with VS Code. Something I've noticed is that the standard C++ intellisense doesn't play so nicely with WinAPI's many macros.

For example,

```
#include <windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(0, "This is a test", "Test", MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, error squiggles appear under "This is a test" and "Test" because VS Code's intellisense is expecting those parameters to be of type LPCWSTR and is instead interpreting them as being const char *.

This shouldn't be the case, as "This is a test" and "Test" are valid as LPCWSTRs and the program compiles and runs perfectly fine.

Is there anyway I can get the intellisense engine to recognize that this is not an error? Or will I have to disable error squiggles entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, VS is working correctly in this case.

"This is a test" is a char const * (LPCSTR), not a LPCWSTR. For a wide character string literal add the 'L' prefix: L"This is a test".

Comment: Actually, that does not solve the issue. It gets rid of the error squiggle in VS Code, but then causes a compilation error as so:
"error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [16]' to 'LPCSTR''
It seems like VS Code is expecting an LPCWSTR while the compiler is expecting an LPCSTR.

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, I need to compile in Unicode mode in order for the L prefix to work. I'd still like to be able to use VS Code to use the ASCII version of WinApi, but this will work for now.

Comment: `"This is a test"` is of type `const char[15]`. @AnthonyRossello: There is no ASCII version of the Windows API. Most functions have an ANSI version, but you shouldn't be using them if at all possible. You are wasting performance on the needless conversions in both directions, potentially suffer from problems with conversions, when Unicode code points cannot be represented in the current code page, and have API calls arbitrarily limit the length of their string inputs due to the conversions they need to perform. Besides, if an answer doesn't address your question, don't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your string with macro `_T(string)` from `<tchar.h>`. Compiles fine and intellisense doesn't panic.